# Sending response in a Pub-Sub architecture

Tags: publish-subscribe

At the moment I have a single AWS EC2 instance which handles all incoming http client requests.  It analyses each request and then decides which back end worker server should handle the request and then makes a http call to the chosen server. The back end server then responds when it has processed the request. The front end server will then respond to the client. The front end server is effectively a load balancer.

I now want to go to a Pub-Sub architecture instead of the front end server pushing the requests to the back end instances.  The front end server will do some basic processing and then simply put the request into an SNS queue and the logic of which back end server  should handle the request is left to the back end servers themselves.

My question is with this model what is the best way to have the back end servers notify the front end server that they have processed the request?  Previously they just replied to the http request the front end server sent but now there is no direct request, just an item of work being published to a queue and a back end instance picking it off the queue.

Answer (score 2):

Pubsub architectures are not well suited to responses/acknowledgements. Their fire-and-forget broadcasting pattern decouples publishers and the subscribers: a publisher does not know if or how many subscribers there are, and the subscribers do no know which publisher generated a message. Also, it can be difficult to guarantee sequence of responses, they won't necessarily match the sequence of messages due to the nature of network comms and handling of messages can take different amounts of time etc. So each message that needs to be acknowledge needs a unique ID that the subscriber can include in its response so the publisher can match a response with the message sent. For example:

1. publisher sends message "new event" and provides a UUID for the
   event
2. many subscribers get the message; some may be the handlers for
   the request, but others might be observers, loggers, analytics, etc
3. if only one subscriber handles the message (e.g. the first
   subscriber to get a key from somewhere), that subscriber generates a
   message "new event handled" and provides a UUID
4. the original
   publisher, as well as any number of other subscribers, may get that
   message;
5. the original publisher sees the ID is
   in its cache as an unconfirmed message, and now marks it as
   confirmed
6. if a certain amount of time passes without receiving a
   confirmation with given ID, the original publisher republishes the
   original message, with a new ID, and removes the old ID from cache.

In step 3, if many subscribers handled the message instead of just one, then it 
less obvious how the original publisher should handle "responses": how does it 
know how many subscribers handle the message, some could be down or 
too busy to respond, or some may be in the process of responding by the time 
the original publisher determines that "not enough handlers have 
responded".

Publish-subscribe architectures should be designed to not request any response, but instead to check for some condition that should have happened as a result of the command being handled, such as a thumbnail having gotten generated (it can assume as a result of a handler of the message).